# Как работают проги для создания виртуальных локальных сетей?

Tags: сеть

Всегда поражало, как программы hamachi, tunngle и прочие могут реализовать обмен данными между пользователями как если бы они были в одной локалке. Как это вообще работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С одной стороны программы есть сокет соединение. С другой TAP драйвер, который отображается как сетевая карта. Программа устанавливает соединение и пересылает данные с сокета в драйвер, забирает пакеты с драйвера и передает в сокет.

Comment: А как реализован так называемый VPN мост? Типо я слышал, что данные передаются по специальному тоннелю.

Comment: @MaGrAs Некоторые штуки, как eoip, l2tpv3, gretap, wireguard работают без сокета, а айписек ещё и без интерфейса. Упаковка реализуется драйвером. Но это не про опенвпн и хаманчи. А мост работает также в этом плане